# Start process and get output and return code for python 3.6

Tags: python

I want to Start process and get output and return code for `python 3.6`.

Currently I have this code but I need something for `python 3.6` (for another machine that I cannot upgrade `python` version):

```
process = subprocess.run(['ll'], capture_output=True, text=True)
return_code = process.returncode
```

Comment: `subprocess.check_output`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run(['ll'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdout
```

It is equivalent to running `subprocess.check_output` that @AKX mentioned in the comment. I don't know if calling `run` directly fits your workflow better.

This code has the benefit of being of being forward compatible too (instead of using the `capture_output` parameter in newer versions, you can still use this).

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'stdout'

Comment: @DanaYeger That's weird, `process` should not be a bytes object but rather `subprocess.CompletedProcess` object, which does have an `stdout` attribute. What code did you run to get this?

Comment: @DanaYeger Look at the full command

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_output` returns a bytes object. You have to convert it into a string using the `decode` method.

```
import subprocess

output_bytes = subprocess.check_output(['ll'])
output_str = output_bytes.decode() # or output_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(output_str)
```

I hope this sums up what you're looking for.